# BSplineCurve Interpolation

Tags: plotting, graphics, interpolation, splines

Can I get interpolated values from this B-spline, (shown in red)?

```
points = {{-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {6, 6}, {10, 7}, {14, 11},
   {18, 2}, {22, 1}, {26, 2}, {30, 1}, {34, 1}};

fn1 = Interpolation[points, Method -> "Spline"];
fn2 = Interpolation[points];

Show[ListPlot[points],
 Graphics[{Red, BSplineCurve[points]}],
 Plot[fn1[x], {x, -2, 36}],
 Plot[fn2[x], {x, -2, 36}],
 AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: The red one is not interpolation - it passes only through the ends, not all points. So you need values of points along B Spline?

Comment: @Vitaliy - It would do to extract the points of the B-spline and interpolate them, but the B-spline is a graphics primitive, and I can't get the data out of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BSplineCurve` is based on `BSplineFunction`. But `BSplineFunction` is *analytic expression* - so you do not need to interpolate it - you can use it as a (parametric) function:

```
g = BSplineFunction[points];
ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If you still need points - this will work with *any step*:

```
bspts=Table[g[t], {t, 0, 1, .1}]
```

Comment: Great question, great answer.  Thanks guys.