# How can I find the points of B Spline functions for a specific range?

Tags: programming, splines

Based on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/bsplinecurve-interpolation):

I have a list of bspline functions (nearly 1000) provided by applying `BSplineFunction` to a list of points. I want to get the points each of bspline function for `Range[0, 1, .1]`.

For instance:

```
functions = {bsplinefunc1, bsplinefunc2, bsplinefunc3};
```

The desired result is:

```
result =
  {bsplinefunc1[0], bsplinefunc1[.1], bsplinefunc1[.2], ..., bsplinefunc1[1]}, 
  {bsplinefunc2[0], bsplinefunc2[.1], bsplinefunc2[.2], ..., bsplinefunc2[1]},
  {bsplinefunc3[0], bsplinefunc3[.1], bsplinefunc3[.2], ..., bsplinefunc3[1]}}
```

I tried to use the solutions of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/how-to-apply-or-map-a-list-of-functions-to-a-list-of-data), mainly István Zachar's answer; however, I couldn't make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Thread` to apply a function to a list of arguments:

```
Thread[bsplinefunc1[Range[0, 1, .1]]]
```

> {bsplinefunc1[0.], bsplinefunc1[0.1], bsplinefunc1[0.2], 
>    bsplinefunc1[0.3], bsplinefunc1[0.4], bsplinefunc1[0.5], 
>    bsplinefunc1[0.6], bsplinefunc1[0.7], bsplinefunc1[0.8], 
>    bsplinefunc1[0.9], bsplinefunc1[1.]}

Now you can use `Map` to use the above on a list of functions:

```
Map[Thread[#[Range[0, 1, .1]]] &, functions]
```

> {{bsplinefunc1[0.], bsplinefunc1[0.1], bsplinefunc1[0.2], 
>     bsplinefunc1[0.3], bsplinefunc1[0.4], bsplinefunc1[0.5], 
>     bsplinefunc1[0.6], bsplinefunc1[0.7], bsplinefunc1[0.8], 
>     bsplinefunc1[0.9], bsplinefunc1[1.]}, {bsplinefunc2[0.], 
>     bsplinefunc2[0.1], bsplinefunc2[0.2], bsplinefunc2[0.3], 
>     bsplinefunc2[0.4], bsplinefunc2[0.5], bsplinefunc2[0.6], 
>     bsplinefunc2[0.7], bsplinefunc2[0.8], bsplinefunc2[0.9], 
>     bsplinefunc2[1.]}, {bsplinefunc3[0.], bsplinefunc3[0.1], 
>     bsplinefunc3[0.2], bsplinefunc3[0.3], bsplinefunc3[0.4], 
>     bsplinefunc3[0.5], bsplinefunc3[0.6], bsplinefunc3[0.7], 
>     bsplinefunc3[0.8], bsplinefunc3[0.9], bsplinefunc3[1.]}}

Answer (score 4):

```
functions={bsplinefunc1,bsplinefunc2,bsplinefunc3};

Outer[#1[#2] &, functions, Range[0, 1, .1]]
```

> {{bsplinefunc1[0.], bsplinefunc1[0.1], bsplinefunc1[0.2],
>   bsplinefunc1[0.3], bsplinefunc1[0.4], bsplinefunc1[0.5],
>   bsplinefunc1[0.6], bsplinefunc1[0.7], bsplinefunc1[0.8],
>   bsplinefunc1[0.9], bsplinefunc1[1.]}, {bsplinefunc2[0.],
>   bsplinefunc2[0.1], bsplinefunc2[0.2], bsplinefunc2[0.3],
>   bsplinefunc2[0.4], bsplinefunc2[0.5], bsplinefunc2[0.6],
>   bsplinefunc2[0.7], bsplinefunc2[0.8], bsplinefunc2[0.9],
>   bsplinefunc2[1.]}, {bsplinefunc3[0.], bsplinefunc3[0.1],
>   bsplinefunc3[0.2], bsplinefunc3[0.3], bsplinefunc3[0.4],
>   bsplinefunc3[0.5], bsplinefunc3[0.6], bsplinefunc3[0.7],
>   bsplinefunc3[0.8], bsplinefunc3[0.9], bsplinefunc3[1.]}}

Answer (score 2):

```
 functions = {bsf1, bsf2, bsf3} (* =  Array[BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {100}]] &, {3}] *);
 range = Range[0, 1, .1];
 Table[f /@ range, {f, functions}]
 Table[f[x], {f, functions}, {x, range}]
```

or

```
 # /@ range & /@ functions
```