# Interpolating a function with splines

Tags: interpolation, splines

I would like to interpolate the following function

```
 g[z_, e_] := 
     PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{e - 2, e + 2}, 
       NormalDistribution[e, 0.3]], z]

    a1 = N[g[-2, 0]];
    a2 = N[g[-1, 0]];
    a3 = N[g[0, 0]];
    a4 = N[g[1, 0]];
    a5 = N[g[2, 0]];
```

With your help I am now using:

```
 k[x_, e_] = 
      Interpolation[{{-2 + e, a1}, {-1 + e, a2},  {0 + e, 
     a3}, {1 + e, a4}, {2 + e, a5}}, 
   Method -> "Spline"] [x];
```

[image]
I need e as an variable, which I can easily access. Can i somehow get rid of the error shown in the picture?
Or do I have to stick to InterpolatingPolynomial? Can i somehow abuse InterpolatingFunction?

Why do i get negative values in the approximation function? Can i get rif of them with other, better methods?

Comment: `Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline"]`?

Comment: have a look at [15879](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/bsplinecurve-interpolation)

Comment: You can take derivatives with that function, and you can get a `BSplineFunction` with explicit parameters, what else do you want?

Comment: The suggestion of @happyfish works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3horZ.png

Comment: I tested the code of the thread you mentioned: points = {{-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {6, 6}, {10, 7}, {14, 11}, {18, 2}, {22, 
    1}, {26, 2}, {30, 1}, {34, 1}};                                                                         g = BSplineFunction[points]            When i now enter g[2], or D[g[t],t] nothing happens. I am little bit lost, sry.

Comment: Maybe you mean you want to differentiate w.r.t. `e`?  You can numerically differentiate: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bxKjR.png

Comment: Thank you for your help. I build in your proposal in my first post and clarfied my problems there.

Comment: your `k` needs to be set delayed: `k[x_, e_] := ... `.  For good measure you might want to do `k[x_, e_?NumericQ] := ... `

Comment: as to why you get negative values, its because you are doing a polynomial interpolation of something that's not a polynomial, with far too few points.  You might have a look at `FunctionInterpolation`, or set `InterpolationOrder->1`

Comment: (1) The error message can be ignored in this case. (2) Why not use the formula returned by `PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{e - 2, e + 2}, NormalDistribution[e, 3/10]], z]` or by `PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{e - 2, e + 2}, NormalDistribution[e, 0.3]], z]`?

Answer (score 2):

This is where a monotonic interpolation method like [Steffen's interpolation](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990A%26A...239..443S) or [Fritsch-Carlson interpolation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717021) is useful. Using the routine from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040):

```
k[x_, e_] := SteffenInterpolation[{{-2 + e, a1}, {-1 + e, a2}, {0 + e, a3},
                                   {1 + e, a4}, {2 + e, a5}}][x]

Plot[k[x, 0], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: monotonic interpolant]